# Missing paging info on SpringDataREST response

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-rest

Is there a way to include page object on `SpringDataREST` Search Resources response?

Example:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/users
```

Returns nice paging object:

```
page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 163,
    "totalPages" : 9,
    "number" : 0
  }
```

But

```
http://localhost:8080/api/users/search/findByNameContainingOrEmailContaining?name=&email=&size=2&page=20
```

Returns no `paging` object on response.

My repository:

```
package br.com.biec.security;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
    public User findByName(@Param("name") String name);
    public List<User> findByNameContainingOrEmailContaining(
            @Param("name") String name,
            @Param("email") String email,
            Pageable p);
}
```

Comment: Could you show the implementation too

Comment: The impl is provided by Spring Data

Answer (score 1):

Found in docs:

To use paging in your own query methods, you need to change the method signature to accept an additional Pageable parameter and **return a Page rather than a List**

So my interface should be:

```
public Page<User> findByNameContainingOrEmailContaining(
            @Param("name") String name,
            @Param("email") String email,
            Pageable p);
```